# How to get a lamp icon at the location of a lamp

Tags: 3d-view

When you first start up Blender 2.6.9 it has a cube, a camera, and a lamp. Both the camera and the lamp have a simple icon-like image that you can see and move around like other objects in the scene. However, sometime during my modeling process these icons have disappeared and when I try to move my light source a circle shows up around where it is but the circle doesn't move when I try to move the light around. Is there a setting or some way to change it back so that I can see the icons for the lamp and camera and move them around again?

**Edit:** I also just found out when I tried to move other objects that the circle shows up for them too, is there a way to make that go away as well? It's kind of annoying and I'm not used to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The large circle you described is showing because you have *Proportional Editing* enabled [image]. Click the icon or use <kbd>O</kbd> to disable it. As for the missing icons, make sure that you didn't hide them accidentally or that you didn't tick *Only Render* under *Display*.

Comment: That fixed the circle, thanks, but it didn't seem to do anything to help make the icons show up, is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: @Roboinventor Use `Ctrl + Spacebar` to make the manipulator appear.

Comment: The manipulators were never gone, just the little light bulb and camera icons where the camera and light bulb are, like this http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Blender3D_StartScreen-2.53.png you can see the little light bulb and camera in the image

Comment: @Roboinventor That scene looks normal to me. I'm not sure what i'm looking for here, can you circle the area(s) or save and attach the blend file.

Comment: I added the picture in an edit to my question so I didn't have to host it somewhere

Comment: @Roboinventor Join me in chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm

Comment: iKIsr: He does not have Proportional Editing enabled.  It's greyed out.

Comment: @MarcClintDion which is why we moved the conversation to chat. He wasn't describing the problem accurately. The screenshot above is what he _wanted_, possibly taken from a default version and not the scene he was in.